# How to Delete Document Using CMIS

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis

I have Created a External web application using Servlets which is connected to alfresco repository.

I am also able to upload document in to the repository, download document from repository.

now my requirement is, i have to delete document based on user role. means i want to give delete document access to only site manager.

Please provide sample code if you have.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please change your question to make it one by one because the answer will be a huge

Comment: @deeps when you download your document does the browser notify the user like having a popup or something like that

Comment: There is no any custom pop-up, But its showing downloaded document at the bottom of browser. what exactly you are looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to delete a document you first need to see if the user have the role to delete this is why the answer will be split in two part

***Part 1 : search for authority***

in this part you will see if the user have the authority to delete

```
Session session = getSession(serverUrl, username, password); // Get the session 

object = session.getObjectByPath(idObject); // get the object 

if (object.getAllowableActions().getAllowableActions().contains(Action.CAN_DELETE_OBJECT)) { //// You can delete 

   } else {  //// You can't delete 
       System.out.println("I can't ");            
   }
```

***Part 2 : delete method***

for a document it is simple to delete it

```
Session session = getSession(serverUrl, username, password);
CmisObject object = session.getObject(path);
Document suppDoc = (Document) object;
suppDoc.delete(true);
```

Note that it's different for a folder , but only the part 2 will be changed ( because when you delete a folder you need to delete his child's)

to complete this answer you only need to combine part 1 with part 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Hi @Yagami can you please share how to delete a folder which has childs?