# How to Increase Document delete time-out period in alfresco 5.0.d

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis, alfresco-webscripts

I am trying to delete some documents from alfresco repository.
But its giving time-out Exception.

So is there any configuration to increase that time-out period.

Or is there any other way to delete documents, in that i will not get read time-out  Exception

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: I've give an answer about a similar question that you asked for [Delete a document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462789/how-to-delete-document-using-cmis/39466711#39466711)

Comment: @YagamiLight  Here i am deleting document from alfresco Share UI, so i just want to increase delete time-out preiod.  Your answer is different...

Comment: Yeah i understand that it's differente you can send your method (to increase the time excution to an executor you can read more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500003/setting-a-maximum-execution-time-for-a-method-thread

Comment: @YagamiLight  Thanks

Comment: @YagamiLight   Yes, Its working.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look to this link it gives a lot of information about CMIS [Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html)  .

About how to make it slower,you can do this by sending your job to an executor : you can lear more and see a complete exemple in [Setting a maximum execution time for a method/thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500003/setting-a-maximum-execution-time-for-a-method-thread) and finnaly you only have to combine the two methods.

Hope that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can configure these values:
- CONNECT_TIMEOUT
- READ_TIMEOUT

More information: https://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/dev-session-parameters.html

Regards,
clv